Compare two boolean arrays considering a tolerance
I have two boolean arrays, first and second that should be mostly equal (up to a tolerance).  I would like to compare them in a way that is forgiving if a few elements are different.
Something like np.array_equal(first, second, equal_nan=True) is too strict because all values must be the same and np.allclose(first, second, atol=tolerance, equal_nan=True) is not suitable for comparing booleans.
The following case should succeed:
tolerance = 1e-5
seed = np.random.rand(100, 100, 100)
first = seed > 0.5
second = (seed > 0.5) & (seed < 1. - 1e-6) # 99.9999% overlap in true elements

The following case should fail:
first = seed > 0.5
second = (seed > 0.5) & (seed < 1. - 1e-4) # 99.99% overlap in true elements

The following case should also fail:
first = seed > 0.5
second = first[::-1] # first.sum() == second.sum(), but they are not similar

How can I handle this case in an elegant manner?

np.mean(first != second) < 1e-6)?

Simon's answer was pretty close to what I needed. However, I preferred using a volume overlapping metric (eg dice and IoU) instead of normalizing by the size of the voxel. Dice and IoU range [0, 1], which is pretty convenient in this case, with 0 meaning no overlap and 1 meaning perfect overlap.
Dice implementation:
tolerance = 1e-5
dice = 2 * (first & second).sum() / (first.sum() + second.sum())
if 1 - dice > tolerance:
    raise


IoU implementation:
iou = (first & second).sum() / (first | second).sum()
if 1 - iou > tolerance:
    raise 


I am glad that you found a suitable answer and also that you shared it. In retrospect, I should have probably inferred from your mentioning of "voxels" in your original question (which since has been edited out by @mkrieger1) that you were actually looking for an overlapping metric :)

A small optimization, to gracefully handle the case of a zero denominator (thus no True voxels in the overlap, which currently raises a runtime warning due to division by zero): you can equivalently reformulate 1 - numerator / denominator > tolerance as (1 - tolerance) * denominator > numerator. E.g. in the IoU case, this would be (1 - tolerance) * (first | second).sum() > (first & second).sum().

You can define your own corresponding closeness comparison:
def close(a, b, tol):
    diff = a != b
    return np.sum(diff) <= tol * np.size(diff)

This will evaluate the ratio of unequal elements to the size of the arrays and thus will produce the relative measure of closeness that you desire. In particular, it will return True for the first example and False for the others.
Some notes:

The current solution implicitly allows for broadcasting; i.e. if the shapes of a and b do not match but are compatible in a broadcasting sense, then the result will be the one for the broadcasted element-wise comparison. If you want to explicitly forbid broadcasting (i.e. only allow arrays of matching shapes), you should include an explicit check for matching shapes (which I originally had included but later removed from the answer).

The current solution implicitly requires that a and b are NumPy arrays, as it assumes that a != b will produce an element-wise comparison. If you want to make it compatible with other Python data types, such as lists, you might want to replace a != b with np.equal(a, b).

The current solution produces a np.bool result. If you want to have a native boolean value instead, you might want to surround the return value with bool(…) or (…).item().


